# Formating Strings in input like tags in HTML

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hey guys i want to use the jquery Autocomplete plugin and instead of separating the tags with , i want to format each tag like displayed in the attached picture.
[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Where have you failed? Show us some code and ask some precise questions!

Comment: i dont know how to create those boxes inside a text input. I cant even imagine how

Comment: We expect you to have attempted to solve this problem by yourself rather than asking the community to arrive at a complete solution for you. When you've got some code to show us that demonstrates some effort by you (even if it's wrong) please update your question and flag to re-open. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, usually it's not a real textbox. It's a fake textbox that has a real, border-less, background-less text input that gets moved around inside a div-that-looks-like-a-textbox.

In the above screenshot, what you have is something like this:

```
  <div class="container">
     <ul class="tags">
       <li>java <span class="closer">x</span></li>
       <li>coldfusion <span class="closer">x</span></li>
     </ul>
     <input type="text" id="tagger"/>
  </div>
```

As you type in the text box, you have JS that auto-completes. When you select a tag (or hit a key like Tab or comma), it takes the current input in the box, creates a new LI, and sticks in the UL with a class of "tags" (ul.tags). The new LI looks like the tag above, and if you float the LIs next to each other, it pushes the textbox over inside the container div (which is styled to look like a textbox). The text input is actually there, just with no border or background, so it looks like it's part of the container textbox.

That's how I've done it in the past. I'm not going to write out all the code for you, but that should get you started. There are other examples of how to do this all over the web if you search correctly.

Hope that helps. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any idea how to build it, then look at something someone else has built. Tagging is a pretty common feature.

http://aehlke.github.com/tag-it/

http://xoxco.com/projects/code/tagsinput/

http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-tagging-tag-clouds/

Answer (score 0):

I am not going to go into too much detail or write you anything customized as your question is far too vague.

Take a look at: http://xoxco.com/projects/code/tagsinput/

I think it does what you after.

Answer (score 0):

There is an existing jQuery plugin for this, called [Tokeninput](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/).